# Which GUI builder has support for many programming languages?

Tags: software-development, gui, ide, programming, gui-builder

Even better would be an IDE with a GUI builder that supports many languages.

The idea is to learn (very) different programming languages in a familiar environment, while writing simple graphic programs.

Languages may include: Rust, ADA, OCAML, LISP

Comment: If it doesn't integrate with an IDE, does it count? I would recommend a GUI library that supports most programming language that people use today. I am afraid, it doesn't support ADA and OCaml.

Comment: Hi!
What are you thinking of specifically? You neglected to write it seems.
Are there any GUI builders without an IDE?

Comment: No, there isn't. Sorry, I misunderstood what you mean. I though you need a GUI library that supports most programming language. In other word, you have to program it from scratch rather than drag and drop GUI components from a GUI builder. I said this because such library exists.